# NSString assume casual values after app goes in background

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

i have a ios window application with ARC
i have a global header that stores the actual language of the game

```
//in Global.h
NSString *language;
NSDictionary *dict;

//in viewDidLoad i have
language=@"en";
```

after the app went to background, when i reactivate the app, i put a

```
NSLog(@"%@",language); // and the result is "<"
```

other NSDictionary are correct.
why?
how can i get rid of this error?
thanks

Comment: Not sure, but I think you need to define the NSString * language in an implementation file as well (.m/.c/.mm), and then use a "local" utility class or function to set/get the variable, or extern the variable.
Anyway, another way is to use a Singleton pattern, which you might consider if this is something that happens a lot in your app. (The implementation, not the bug :-)

Comment: It actually worked for me..where did you log the value?

Comment: I too cannot reproduce this behavior. Perhaps if you could develop and make available a small test program that reproduces the behavior you are seeing, that would be helpful. There must be some additional important details that remain unclear. Perhaps you have some code that is altering the language variable and don't yet realize it is being executed.

Comment: makeing a singleton that handles this variables, this not happen anymore